Trying to show call dialog when I receive calls using from FCM notifications and app is closed or in background mode
I am trying to open a calling dialog where user can answer or decline a call when notification is sent from FCM dashboard. When app is opened calling dialog shows and I am able to answer or decline but when app is closed or in background the calling dialog does not show but rather shows as normal push notification.
This is my class where I receive the notification
public class NotificationReceive extends FirebaseMessagingService {
String  pic;
String  title;
String  message;
String receiverid;
String senderId, senderName, senderImage, roomName, callType, status;

@SuppressLint("WrongThread")
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e("NotificationReceive", "Normal notifs called");

    if (remoteMessage == null || remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("NotificationReceive", "RemoteMessage is null or data payload is empty");
        return;
    }

    Log.e("Notification Payload", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    if (remoteMessage.getData().get("action_type").equals("NEW_MESSAGE")) {
        Log.e("NotificationReceive", "Handling normal text notification");

        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        receiverid = remoteMessage.getData().get("receiverid");
        pic = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");

        Functions.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString(Variables.SOCIAL_INFO_JSON, "{}").commit();

        final String user_id = Functions.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Variables.FB_ID, "");
        Log.d("NotificationReceive", "User ID: " + user_id);

        if (user_id.equals(receiverid)) {
            sendNotification sendNotification = new sendNotification(this);
            sendNotification.execute(pic);
        }
    }
    else{
        
        Log.e("NotificationReceive", "Handling call notification");

        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        pic = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        receiverid = remoteMessage.getData().get("receiverid");

        senderId = remoteMessage.getData().get("senderid");
        senderName = remoteMessage.getData().get("senderName");
        senderImage = remoteMessage.getData().get("senderImage");
        roomName = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        callType = remoteMessage.getData().get("call_type");
        status = remoteMessage.getData().get("action_type");

        if (senderImage != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("CALL_TOKEN", senderImage);
            editor.apply();
        }

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("id", receiverid);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("name", senderName);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("image", "");
            serviceIntent.putExtra("status", status);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("call_type",callType);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("roomname", roomName);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("zoomReceiverToken", senderImage);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }

}

 private class sendNotification extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

     Context ctx;


     public sendNotification(Context context) {
         super();
         this.ctx = context;
     }


     @Override
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

         InputStream in;
         try {

             URL url = new URL(params[0]);
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             connection.setDoInput(true);
             connection.connect();
             in = connection.getInputStream();
             Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
             return myBitmap;


         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }


     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

         super.onPostExecute(result);

         try {
             final String CHANNEL_ID = receiverid;
             final String CHANNEL_NAME = receiverid;

             Intent notificationIntent;


             notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, SplashA.class);
             notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

             PendingIntent pendingIntent=null;
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent,
                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
             }else {
                 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
             }

             NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ctx.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                 NotificationChannel defaultChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                 notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(defaultChannel);
             }


             Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
             NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx,CHANNEL_ID);

             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                 builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.humboo_icon);
             } else {
                 builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.humboo_icon);
             }

             builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
                     .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                     .setLargeIcon(result)
                     .setContentTitle(title)
                     .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                     .setContentText(message)
                     .setAutoCancel(true)
                     .setSound(soundUri)
                     .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
                     .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

             Notification notification = builder.build();
             notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
             notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
             notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }

}
 }

and this is my CallService class
public class CallService extends Service {
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "call_channel";
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String senderId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        String senderName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String image = intent.getStringExtra("image");
        String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
        String callType = intent.getStringExtra("call_type");
        String roomName = intent.getStringExtra("roomname");
        String token = intent.getStringExtra("zoomReceiverToken");
        showForegroundNotification(senderId, senderName, image, status, callType, roomName, token);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Call Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("Channel for call notifications");
        channel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE), new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .build());
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

private void showForegroundNotification(String senderId, String senderName, String image, String status, String callType, String roomName, String token) {
    createNotificationChannel();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    // Intent for answering the call
    Intent answerIntent = new Intent(this, MeetingActivity.class);
    answerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    //answerIntent.putExtra("call_action", "answer");
    answerIntent.putExtra("id", senderId);
    answerIntent.putExtra("name", senderName);
    answerIntent.putExtra("image", image);
    answerIntent.putExtra("status", status);
    answerIntent.putExtra("call_type", callType);
    answerIntent.putExtra("roomname", roomName);
    answerIntent.putExtra("zoomReceiverToken", token);
    answerIntent.putExtra("straightAnswer", "answer");
    PendingIntent answerPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, answerIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    Intent declineIntent = new Intent(this, CallActionReceiver.class);
    declineIntent.setAction("DECLINE_CALL");
    PendingIntent declinePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, declineIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    Notification notification = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        // Creating a notification with Notification.CallStyle
        Icon icon = Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_user_icon);
        Person caller = new Person.Builder()
                .setIcon(icon)
                .setName(senderName)
                .setImportant(true)
                .build();
        Notification.CallStyle notificationStyle = Notification.CallStyle.forIncomingCall(caller, declinePendingIntent, answerPendingIntent);
        notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call)
                .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
                .setContentText("Incoming call from " + senderName)
                .setStyle(notificationStyle)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .build();
    } else {
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Incoming Call from " + senderName)
                //.setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call, "Answer", answerPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_end_white_24px, "Decline", declinePendingIntent)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE))
                .build();
    }

    if (notification != null) {
        startForeground(1, notification);
    } else {
        Log.e("CallService", "Failed to create notification");
        stopSelf();
    }
}

